# Using CFFI to call C-function with OpenMP from Python

Tags: python, openmp, python-cffi

I am using CFFI to call a C function with OpenMP from Python. My code works on one of my computers, but not the other with a very similar setup.

```
import os
from cffi import FFI

# test 
os.system("gcc -fopenmp -c test.c -o test.o")
os.system("gcc -o test.exe test.o -fopenmp")
os.system("test.exe")

# gateway
ffi = FFI()
os.system("gcc -o test.so test.c -shared -fopenmp")
ffi.cdef(r''' int main(); ''')        
lib = ffi.dlopen(r'''test.so''')
lib.main()
```

The error is

```
OSError: cannot load library test.so: error 0x45a
```

I am using Python 3.5 (the latest Anaconda distribution) and TDM-GCC 5.1.0.
The test runs on both computers. What can explain the difference behavior?

Comment: Try running with `LD_DEBUG=all`.

Answer (score 1):

Short version - you define your header (.h) and source files (.c) as usual with cffi. For openmp you have to include extra compile and linker arguments as follows:

```
import cffi

ffi = cffi.FFI()    
ffi.cdef(header_string)    
ffi.set_source(
    '_my_module_name',
    source_string,
    extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'],
    extra_link_args=['-fopenmp'],
)
ffi.compile()
import _my_module_name
```